# AWS Global Services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to understand how many Global services does AWS has.
We all know Route53, IAM, CloudFront, WAF are Global.
But also, according to AWS docs: "Due to the nature of the service, some AWS services are delivered globally rather than regionally, such as Amazon Route 53, Amazon Chime, Amazon WorkDocs, Amazon WorkMail, Amazon WorkSpaces, Amazon WorkLink."

But why Chime/WorkDocs/etc are Global? In my web console, I see them as regional ones.
What are the signs that I can understand that they are global?

Is there a list of global services out there at all?
Like I've seen that Server Certificates and SES are Global as well, but why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only 'real' global services are:

- **Amazon CloudFront:** Operates out of [hundreds of locations around the world](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc)
- **Amazon Route 53:** Operates out of [dozens of locations around the world](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/features/)
- **Amazon IAM:** Permission changes in one region are automatically copied to all regions

Some services are in only one location, such as Amazon Chime (it's like Slack).

Contrary to what that page says, I think that the Work* services are actually regional.

Comment: Note that in spite of S3 being Regional in terms of physical storage, S3 names are global logically.

Comment: What about the cost explorer and the 'support' service? They are also global AFAIK
Also there's the - quite new - 'EC2 Global View' which is by definition also global

Comment: @Kutzi Yes, you could claim those as global, but Cost Explorer and Support don't actually use or deploy any services on your behalf. And a 'global view' is just a view -- similar to viewing all S3 buckets, but not actually deploying resources globally.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if you have a look in the AWS Console, support and cost explorer are named 'Service', too.
I guess the question was not very clear on which type of services were meant